# Duda desglose de un número en SQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo que crear un programa, al que yo le introduzca por teclado un importe, y me diga la cantidad de (billetes de 100€, billetes de 50€, billetes de 10€ etc...) que puede haber en ese importe.

Para probar, solo he empezado con el billete de 10€, para que sea más fácil desglosar el importe.

Y tengo esto:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`Dinero` $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`Dinero` (in numero int) // eso que está entre paréntesis, será el importe que yo meteré por teclado

BEGIN

  declare b_diez; //Aqui declaro la variable (Billete de 10);

  set b_diez = 0; // Y aqui la inicializo poniendola el valor 0;

    if numero >= 10 then
        set b_diez = numero / 10;
        set numero = MOD(numero,10);
    end if;


  select b_diez;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Necesito ayuda con dos cosas:

1. Algún consejo para poder hacer mejor este ejercicio y para entenderlo.
2. Me sale error de sintaxis:

   ```
   Linea: 4    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';
   set b_diez = 0;

     if numero >= 10 then
       set b_diez = numero / 10;
   ...' at line 4.
   ```

Gracias

Comment: Por qué poner como etiqueta sql-server a la pregunta, ¡no me lo explico!

Comment: MySQL no soporta comentarios de la forma `//` (no es C). Los comentarios al final de una línea en mySQL empiezan por un `#`, o por `-- ` (el espacio después de `--` es importante). También soporta comentarios entre `/* */`

Comment: si, esos comentarios los he puesto a la hora de hacer la pregunta, para que se entienda.

Comment: Publica el código tal cual te da el error, entonces, porque al modificarlo introduces nuevos errores que, probablemente, impiden ver cual es el problema que realmente tienes. Y el código se explica por si mismo, los comentarios, EMHO, están de más.